# Need to zip text files from a predefined location & save the zipped files in another location of hard disk using windows services

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

Need to zip text files from a predefined location & save the zipped files in another location of hard disk using windows services & delete the old text file (a scheduled service)

I tried the following code in which i used 'icsharpcode' for zipping the files. But after installing the service.. i am getting a message that "this services has started & then stopped..." without showing any required output.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Design;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

namespace createzip
{

    public partial class createzip : ServiceBase
{
Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public createzip()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onelapsedtime);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 60000;  
 }
 protected override void OnStop()
```

{

```
        timer1.Enabled = false;

}
 private void onelapsedtime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        string folder = "@E:\\zipped files";
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(folder);
        string output = "@E:\\output";
        string outputfilename = Path.Combine(output, "this file is zipped");
        using (var x = new ZipFile(output))
        {
            foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
                x.Add(f);
        }
        string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        using ( ZipOutputStream s = new     

   ZipOutputStream(File.Create(output)))                //(args[1])))
        {
            s.SetLevel(9);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            foreach (string file in filenames)
            {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
                //entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                s.PutNextEntry(entry);
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    int sourcebytes;
                    do
                    {
                        sourcebytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        s.Write(buffer, 0, sourcebytes);
                    }
                    while (sourcebytes > 0);
                }
            }
            s.Finish();
            s.Close();
            return;
        }

    }



}  

}
```

Comment: You have to start the timer in the `OnStart()` function: `timer1.Start()`

Comment: One problem is that you probably need to have an infinite loop in the start method so that the service permanently runs if this is a Windows Service? A much more simpler and easy to maintain solution would be to convert it to a console application, take out the time code and use Task Scheduler to invoke it..

Comment: @RononDex i tried, its not working with that additional line of code

Comment: Strange, did you place that line at the end of OnStart()? It should work that way. I have used this code by myself a few times for windows services.

Comment: @RononDex  Not working.. am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;


namespace trail2zip
{
    public partial class trail2zip : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer;
        string path1 = @"E:\zipped files\New Text Document.txt";
        string path2 = @"E:\output\filezipname.zip";
        string path3 = @"E:\zipped files\R_23122015.txt";


        int timerInterval = 60000;

        public trail2zip()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Interval = timerInterval;
            timer.Enabled = true;

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer.Stop();
            timer.SynchronizingObject = null;
            timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;


        }
        public void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(path2);       //(filezipname);
            z.BeginUpdate();
            z.Add(path1);
            z.Add(path3);
            z.CommitUpdate();
            z.Close();


        }
    }
}
```